# Is it possible to get DB name with sqlite3 gem in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I have the SQLite3::Database object created with such code `@db = SQLite3::Database.open(db)`. Can I get database name using methods/attributes of this object?

Comment: If you call @db.methods in irb you can see all methods on the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SQLite3::Pragrams::database_list`](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/classes/SQLite3/Pragmas.html#M000027):

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.open('a')
db.database_list
# => [[0, "main", "/tmp/a"]]
db.database_list[0][2]
# => "/tmp/a"
```

Also see [`PRAGMA database_list;` from Pragma statements supoorted by SQLite](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `db` passed to `SQLite3::Database.open` is usually filename in SQLite.  What do you mean `This is known`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, In the example code `/tmp/a` is actual path of the database file.

Comment: what does `0` and `'main'` stand for ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, According to the documentation I linked in the answer, *The second column is the "main" for the main database file, "temp" for the database file used to store TEMP objects, or the name of the ATTACHed database for other database files.*   IMHO, first columns seems to be some kind of internal identifier. (not clearly documented)

Comment: `#database_list` method lists the database names associated with `db`. But to which it currently points to, how to know that ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, The third column is the name of the database file itself . I think that is what OP want.

Comment: Its Okay.. I am convinced.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, According to [SQLite3::Database](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/classes/SQLite3/Database.html), *The Database class encapsulates a **single connection** to a SQLite3 database.* ; IMHO, no currently connected database concept like other DBMS.

Comment: @falsetru... Yes..your last comment completely makes sense! :)

Comment: @falsetru, your code not works for me. But it works with db.execute('PRAGMA database_list') method. What am I doing wrong? And, yes, the name of the database file itself - is what I want.

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure. What does `@db.database_list` return?

Comment: undefined method `database_list' for #<SQLite:0x00000000a690a0> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Michael, I used sqlite-ruby version 1.3.6 (http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/) with Ruby 1.9.3.   And inspecting `db` object give me `#<SQLite3::Database:0x9fbb108>`, not `#<SQLite:0x0000000...>`. Maybe we are using different library... or you are using lower version of the library.

Comment: @falsetru, yes - it's ok. Something was wrong with my code before. Thanks for your help.